# Horizontally scrollable without scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to mimic the behavior of `overflow-y:hidden` to `overflow-x`, but it doesn't behave the same way. `overflow-x:hidden` doesn't allow to scroll (by dragging the mouse).

See: http://jsfiddle.net/Gxm2z/

```
#container {
    width: 300px
}
#modules {
    height: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.module {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ddd;
}
```

How can I achieve the same result without a scroll bar? I'm ok with a javascript/jQuery plugin.

The plan is to use arrows, and maybe a custom scrollbar

Comment: You can use absolute positioning for the inner element, then use the button to change the top/left position.

Comment: What about javascript? http://davetayls.me/jquery.kinetic/ << for touch drag http://jquery-plugins.net/tiny-scrollbar-cross-browser-lightweight-jquery-scrollbar << scrollbar

Comment: one extra inner wrapper? or on #modules?

Comment: You can try http://iscrolljs.com/ it's weel documented and easy to remove the scroll bar without loosing the scroll capabilities.

Comment: Mr. Alien thank you, I stumbled on that while looking for a solution, and most likely a custom scrollbar will be used

Comment: to stay in 2014, transition + text indent could be used for the arrow idea. else padding-bottom and margin-bottom could also have been used to hide the scrollbar . example http://jsfiddle.net/28m6pq0h/1/ inspired from 8 years ago : http://dabblet.com/gist/3623906

Answer (score 27):

this is my solution CSS based - simple and nice on all devices, no need for additional JS.

- add fixed height and overflow hidden to parent element (in your case `#container`)
- enlarge height of `#modules` - this create enough place hidden under parent element for scrollbar (because of smaller `#container` height, this place is invisible)
- using `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;` is good choice, make nice behavior on iPad and iPhone

  ```
  #container {
      width: 300px;
      height: 60px;
      overflow: hidden;
  }
  #modules {
      height: 90px; /* 40px - more place for scrollbar, is hidden under parent box */
      padding: 5px;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow-x: scroll;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
  ```

live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/s6wcudua/

Comment: works without overflow-y: hide; (should probably be 'hidden')

Comment: Nice solution, but how do users scroll on a non-touch device?

Comment: @isapir: Move the cursor over the area, then hold `shift` while using the scroll wheel or equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

```
#modules {
    height: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    &::-webkit-scrollbar {
       display: none;
    }
}
```

This only work in webkit based browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `::-webkit-scrollbar` pseudo element, like shown [here.](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-styling-scrollbars-to-match-your-ui-design--webdesign-9430)

Answer (score 0):

http://iscrolljs.com/

Best Javascript custom scrollbar available, in my opinion. It will work great in Mobile, IE9+ and modern browsers. Plenty of options and callbacks. And yes, you can disable the visible scrollbar, but still retain horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

```
#parent {
    width: A px;
    height: B px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#child {
   width: C px; 
   height: (greater_than_B) px;
   overflow-x: auto;
}
```

1-Make overflow hidden in parent.

2-Make hight of child modules greater than parent so that scrolls are hide