# Horizontal Scrolling List display HTML CSS(Currently displaying vertically with scroll)

Tags: html, css, angularjs, horizontal-scrolling

I have just started with HTML & CSS with angular & I have been trying to achieve this scrolling list for a while but not sure how to implement it.

I can implement it with li and ul elements but for this specific example where I am iterating through using *ngFor, im not sure how to do it..

I want to achieve something like this :
[image]

Currently, my app displays like this: (with vertical scrolling ability)
[image]

How do I get my flights to display in a list horizontally that will scroll across? 
My Code:

flight-viewer-html:

```
<h3>Flights </h3>
<div class= "grid grid-pad">
    <a *ngFor="let flight of flights" class="col-1-4">
        <div class ="module flight">
            <h4>{{flight.number}}</h4>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

flight-viewer.css:

```
h3 {
    text-align: center; margin-bottom: 0;
}
h4 {
    position: relative;
}


.module {
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #eee;
    max-height: 120px;
    min-width: 120px;
    background-color: #607D8B;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.module:hover {
    background-color: #EEE;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #607d8b;
}
```

Any help / pointers would be appreciated!

edit: solved

Thanks

Comment: Did you try with any slider plugin?

Comment: Check this out : http://jsfiddle.net/s6wcudua/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horizontally scrollable without scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25067224/horizontally-scrollable-without-scrollbar)

Comment: @vel no what do you mean?

Comment: If you can do it with UL LI, why don't you?

Comment: how would i use UL LI and iterate through the flights with ngfor? @Salketer

Comment: replace the 2 divs, the first by UL and the inner div by li ... ? *ngFor shouldn't impact what you can or cannot use in html

Comment: @Salketer thanks! only started HTML with angular recently not really up to scratch